# How to disable triple click in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to disable the "Triple click to select the entire line" feature in IntelliJ IDEA? I found it very disturbing.

Comment: What behavior do you expect on the triple click ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To activate the "**select camel case word**" on triple click you must add this option into your *idea.properties* file :

```
idea.honor.camel.humps.on.triple.click = true
```

The option is not available into the ide setting since the 110.179 build.

[Source](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-75680#)

Comment: Got it to work! I need to enable the Editor.SmartKeys->"Use CamelHumps words" ^_^

Comment: This solution is a bit old but it still works. I'm using webstorm 11.0.3. Thanks.

Comment: is it possible, that this solution stopped working in recent builds?